# Sentinel::check() always return FALSE in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

This is my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/xx', 'xx\yy@zz');
```

This is my modification in Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
    \Keevitaja\Linguist\LocalizeUrls::class,
```

LocalizeUrls.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->linguist->hasDefaultSlug() && $this->linguist->isDefaultDenied()) {
            abort(404);
        }

        if (Sentinel::check())
        {
            dd("logged in");
        }

        dd("NOT logged in");
```

I am using Sentinel and Linguist for authentication and localisation. 
I would like to get 'system_language' from the User model: check if the user is logged in and if he is, I would like to get his preferred language from the DB and then pass it to Linguist:

```
$this->linguist->localize('fr');
```

Unfortunately, `Sentinel:check()` always returns FALSE in this middleware. In my own middleware it is working well.

For sure, I am using the right Facade of Sentinel, because `$sentinel = Sentinel::findById(1);` returns a valid result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused because of the order in the Kernel.php `$middlewareGroups` where `\Keevitaja\Linguist\LocalizeUrls::class` was on first position.